# Where are Duties (table name) stored in AX?

Tags: x++, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to access Security duties (in code), but I don't know where they are stored (in which table)?

Privileges are stored in SecurityTask, now I need to know where duties are stored in AX 2012.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it here: http://arsalanax.blogspot.be/2012/02/role-based-security-in-ax.html

Roles are stored in SecurityRole

User to role mappings in SecurityUserRole

Duties & privileges stored in SecurityTask

Duty to privileges mappings are stored in SecuritySubTask

Role to duty mappings are stored in SecurityRoleTaskGrant

UPDATE (query added)

```
SecurityTaskEntryPoint  taskEntryPoint;
SecurityRole            role;
SecurityRoleTaskGrant   taskGrant;
SecuritySubTask         subTask;
SecurityTask            privilege;
str privName;
str dutyName;
str entrName;
str accessLevel;
;

while select taskEntryPoint
join subTask
    where subTask.SecuritySubTask == taskEntryPoint.SecurityTask
join taskGrant
    where taskGrant.SecurityTask == subTask.SecurityTask
join role
    where role.RecId == taskGrant.SecurityRole
    &&  role.AotName like 'Sales*'
    //|| role.AotName like 'System*'
{
     if (subTask.RecId)
    {
        switch (taskEntryPoint.PermissionGroup)
        {
            case AccessRight::View:
                accessLevel = "R";
                break;
            case AccessRight::Edit:
                accessLevel = "U";
                break;
            case AccessRight::Add:
                accessLevel = "C";
                break;
            case AccessRight::Delete:
                accessLevel = "D";
                break;
            default:
                accessLevel = "";
                break;
        }
    }

    select privilege
        where privilege.RecId == taskGrant.SecurityTask
        && SecurityTaskType::Duty == privilege.Type;
    dutyName = privilege.AotName;

    select privilege
        where privilege.RecId == subTask.SecuritySubTask
        && SecurityTaskType::Privilege == privilege.Type;
    privName = privilege.AotName;

    info(strFmt("EP: %1, Pr: '%2', Du: %3, Ro: %4, Ac: %5", taskEntryPoint.EntryPoint, privName, dutyName, role.AotName, accessLevel));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Security duties are in table `SecurityTask` with Type equal to 1 (SecurityTaskType::Duty).

Security privileges are in table `SecurityTask` with Type equal to 0 (SecurityTaskType::Privilege)

Security process cycles are in table `SecurityTask` with Type equal to 2 (SecurityTaskType::ProcessCycle).

All these objects are also in table (or rather view) `SysModelElement` (Duties with ElementType == 135).

Comment: Please have a look at my answer above. I can refer to SecurityTask in a join statement to get the aotName, right?

Comment: Do you need a join? A single select on `SecurityTask` should suffice. What are you trying to do? I see no join or select in your answer.

Comment: I'm trying to get entry points from privileges, for several roles. In the AOT - Entry points are found under privileges, privileges are found under duties, and duties under a role. This is how I organize access rights. Please take a look at my answer which is updated with the query.